# Not able to install Firefox extension for Capybara tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, capybara

I have developed a Firefox extension that adds a toolbar to certain websites I visit. Now I am trying to write some acceptance tests for the same using Capybara and RSpec.

Here's my spec_helper.rb :

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium/webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :firefox do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile.add_extension '/Users/some_user/Projects/some_project/dev/firefox/some_extension.xpi'
  firefox_options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
  firefox_options.profile = profile
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, options: firefox_options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :firefox
```

But when the tests run, Firefox doesn't seem to have that extension installed. I've tried installing the same extension using the Firefox GUI and that works.

I have two questions:

1. Why am I not able to load the extension for my test run?
2. Is using Capybara for my use case a good idea

Some more info:

- I have Firefox v61 on a Mac
- I have a Chrome extension for which I have written some acceptance tests using Capybara and they work just fine.

Comment: what if you use `Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, options: firefox_options, profile: profile)`?

Comment: @fabersky That didn't help. Although, looking at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/options.rb#L43, it shouldn't have mattered I think.